# How generate CSR for wildcard multidomain certificates

Tags: ssl, certificate, wildcard, csr

I want to buy a multidomain wildcard certificate for 2 domains: *.domain1.org and *.domain2.org

How i should generate the CSR? Because I have tried to generate it using as common name *.domain1.org but the website where I try to buy not accept wildcard in the common name. In addition, if I only specify one domain in common name, it would be valid for the other domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a **Multi Domain wildcard** certificate the CSR is to be generated for a non wildcard domain name (like www.domain.com or domain.com).

While completing your order, you have to specify the **Wildcard domain names** in the Additional domain names list as follows:

- *.domain1.com
- *.domain2.com

Comment: What is most recommended? Create it for www.domain1.org or domain1.org?
In my case I want to use the certificate (plus a website www.domain1.org) in a IMAP server (imap.domain1.org, imap.domain2.org) and SMTP server (smtp.domain1.org, smtp.domain2.org).

Answer (score 0):

You will need one certificate for each domain. You can't place the wildcard where the domain should be. `*.domain1.org` and `*.domain2.org` will work. But `*.org` will not.